# How to find the slope of a line when you only have a point and an angle?

Tags: geometry

A line passing through $(4,7)$ makes an angle of $45$ degrees with the $y$-axis. How do I find the slope of this line?

Comment: The slope of a nonvertical line is the tangent of the angle it makes with the $x$-axis (measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis). Can you relate that angle to the angle you are using?

Comment: So, the angle it makes with the x-axis is 45 degrees. What do you mean by relate it to the angle?

Comment: I was speaking in general terms. If a line makes an angle of $d$ degrees measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, then it makes an angle of $90-d$ degrees measure clockwise from the positive $y$-axis. For example, if the $x$-axis ctclkws angle is $30^{\circ}$ then then $y$-axis clkws angle is $60^{\circ}$.

Comment: And yes, it's also $45^{\circ}$. So the slope is $\tan 45^{\circ} = 1$.

Comment: Remember $\text{slope} = \tan \psi$ where $\psi$ is the angle from the _x_-axis and counter clockwise.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch this line out. Draw a xy-plane and draw a line through $(4, 7)$ that looks like it makes a $45^\circ$ angle with the y-axis. Now, call the y-intercept $(0, b)$. Now, make a right triangle with vertical and horizontal legs using $(0, b)$ and $(4, 7)$ as the endpoints of the hypotenuse. $(0, 7)$ should be the vertex at the right angle.

Now, this line makes a $45^\circ$ angle with the y-axis. This triangle has that angle in it, so this triangle is a $45^\circ-45^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle. This means that the legs are equal. One leg goes from $(0, b)$ to $(0, 7)$ and thus has length $7-b$. The other goes from $(0, 7)$ to $(4, 7)$, meaning it has length $4$. Solving the equation $7-b=4$, we get $b=3$. Now, the slope can be found from $(0, 3)$ and $(4, 7)$, giving us a slope of $m=1$.

Now, using the fact that $y=mx+b$, we get the equation $y=x+3$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.